# Диалоги по типу ВК. Структура БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

С двумя собеседниками вроде просто

```
dialogs
id --- id_user1 --- id_user2 --- last_msg

messages
id --- id_dlg --- user_from --- text_msg
```

Но не пойму, как организовать структуру, когда в диалогах может быть множество участников. Нужно больше, чем 2 таблицы?

Comment: [статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/company/vkontakte/blog/342570/) в тему

Comment: Так же у них в группе VKTech есть видео с выступлением Дмитрия Егорова на HighLoad++

Comment: Переносим `id_user1` и `id_user2` в третью таблицу `members: id_dlg --- id_user` да и всё

Comment: Обычная связь многие-ко-многим?

Answer (score 1):

Делаем таблицу `message: id -- user_id -- dialog_id -- time -- text` `user_id` и `dialog_id` делаем внешними ключами и по ним уже тянем данные о пользователях в диалоге и о самом диалоге. Возможно можно получше придумать, но это первое, что пришло в голову